# Reconnecting (dial tcp [(IPv6 addr)]:443: connect: network is unreachable)

Tags: linux, ubuntu-16.04, ngrok

My django server is running with port 9000 and I am trying to run ngrok for my local django server with the following command

```
./ngrok http 192.168.7.171:9000
```

But it is throwing 2 errors as

```
reconnecting (dial tcp [2600:1f16:59e:b200:7dc6:8c66:d95b:e236]:443: connect: network is unreachable)
```

then

```
reconnecting (read tcp 192.168.7.171:57604->52.15.196.176:443: i/o timeout)
```

The error is shown as below in terminal,

```
Session Status                reconnecting (read tcp     192.168.7.171:47454->18.216.22.45:443: i/o timeout)                                        
Update                        update available (version 2.3.27, Ctrl-U to update)                                                              
Version                       2.2.8                                                                                                            
Region                        United States (us)                                                                                               
Web Interface                 http://127.0.0.1:4040                                                                                            

Connections                   ttl     opn     rt1     rt5     p50     p90                                                                      
                              0       0       0.00    0.00    0.00    0.00
```

Could anyone help me out of this issue?

Comment: okay. @jww  Thank you. But I did not find any forum in stack Exchange Network with the tag "ngrok". So please suggest where should I post this question.